# How to create an Information Management Policy Setting in Office365 SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, information-management

I have setup the public-facing website and created a document library in Office365 SharePoint Online.

I would like to configure an Information Management Policy Setting for the document library that defines document retention.

I have been following the instructions in the section entitled 'Create a policy for a list, library or folder' in the link:

Create and apply information management policies - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/create-and-apply-information-management-policies-HA101631505.aspx

I opened the public-facing website using Microsoft SharePoint Designer and then viewed the 'Documents' library under 'Lists and Libraries'.

When I click the ribbon button 'Administration Web Page' I do not have the link 'Information management policy settings' under 'Permissions and Management'. The only links I have under 'Permissions and Management' are:

- Permissions for this document library
- Manage files which have no checked in version
- Workflow Settings

Something just isn't right here.

I can't see where I can configure this setting.

Can someone guide me please.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Walter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public facing site of SharePoint Online is not a full featured version of SharePoint. This is why you do not see the Information Management Policy. Below is what is listed in the Service Description.

Public Website: Designed for small businesses and professionals to market their business with a simple and professional public website. This site is intended for simple, low-traffic, branded websites to display business information, location, maps, directions, and contact information. This site is managed via a new tool called Site Designer for personalization and builds off of simple out-of-the-box web templates. Office 365 customers can create only one simple public website per tenancy. And once created, customers are able to apply a vanity URL—such as http://www.contoso.com—that they have procured outside of Office 365.
 Note 
•   Vanity URLs can only be applied to the public website. Customers cannot apply a vanity URL to an intranet zone site.
•   **The public website does not grant use rights to leverage the SharePoint publishing portal components.** These features are only supported for intranet sites within the private site collections created in the SharePoint Online Administration Center. The public website is configurable by use of the built-in Site Designer ribbon tool. 
•   Editing the Public Website with SharePoint Designer is not supported.