# Sharepoint Version in word

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, version

Is there a way of embedding the SharePoint file version number in a Word document? Importantly, I'm using **Word 2013** and **SharePoint Online****.

Various methods are discussed online but, for example, the process documented [here](http://www.smackwagondesign.com/how-to-add-the-sharepoint-version-number-to-a-word-document/) doesn't seem to be available on SharePoint Online. The screenshot shows that the *Information Management Policy Settings* option isn't present, so labels cannot be enabled or set.
[image: Sharepoint Document Library Settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Enable the versioning for the library.
2. Create a new Calculated column with this formula: =Version, and add it to the default view.
3. Check if the version information is available in the library's default view.
4. If you can get the version information, try to set the labels value with the new added column.

For more details check:

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/178074.aspx

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/53011.aspx

Comment: I've successfully completed steps 1 - 3. However, step 4 is problematic. Both documents referenced by Aanchal refer to 'Sharepoint Document Library Settings -> Information Management Policy Settings -> Document -> Enable Labels and then Label format "{Version}"'. The _Information Management Policy Setting_ option isn't present under _Sharepoint Document Library Settings_.

Comment: It is present under Libaray settings. Which plan are you using?

Comment: I'm using SharePoint Online (Plan 1).

Comment: is this your problem? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37102/how-to-create-an-information-management-policy-setting-in-office365-sharepoint-o

Comment: It was - I was in the public site. I've now created a new site, followed your process and it works. Thanks!

Comment: The Links don't work! :(

Comment: here's also a blog that describes this method http://www.codebycody.com/2011/07/add-sharepoint-version-number-to-word.html